# "op_over_source_max" error when using pathPaymentStrictReceive operation

Tags: transactions

I'd like to send 10 USDC to a receiver, I specify the same value in **'amount'** and **'sendMax'** strong textfields, and I'm getting **"op_over_source_max"** error at the end.
When specifying any amount higher than 10 in sendMax field, my transaction is successful.
Could you please let me know what value should be specified in sendMax field?

```
StellarSdk.Operation.pathPaymentStrictReceive( {
      sendAsset:  StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
      sendMax: "10",
      destination: receiver.publicKey,
      destAsset:   new StellarSdk.Asset("USDC","GBBD47IF6LWK7P7MDEVSCWR7DPUWV3NY3DTQEVFL4NAT4AQH3ZLLFLA5" ),
      destAmount: "10" ,
      path: [new StellarSdk.Asset("VCAD","GDJB54PLFIPJLMQAFFREBTAZNETONH3SR5JKT4XZEDV7PDMUOBCMBH4A" ), new StellarSdk.Asset("BRC", "GBBQQ6OPJFZDL2KTYSGZFCYOALVBOD3QFNN4A3NLOE445RJQAMZPZTW4" )],
    } );
```

> To create a transaction, I'm using testnet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send 10 USDC while only spending (sendMax) 10 XLM, unfortunately, XLM is not worth 1 USDC at the moment ;-)